# puxar informações via ajax do php

Tags: php, html, ajax

boa tarde, estou estudando ajax e estou tentando fazer um input passar para um arquivo via post, porem nada acontece.. estou acompanhando via firebug do chrome e vejo que sempre o **type: 'post'** está com erro.

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
function ajax(nome){
    info = {"nNome" : nome};

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post';
        url: "arquivo.php";
        data: info,
    }).done(function(data) {
        data = $.parseJSON(data);
        $(".resultado span.nome").text(data.nNome);
    });
}

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("input[name=Enviar]").click(function(){
            var nome = $("input[name=nome]").val();
        });

    });

</script>

<form>
<label>Entre com seu nome:</label>
<input type="text" name="nome"><br>
<input type="button" name="Enviar" value="Enviar">
</form>

<div class="resultado">
Olá, <span class="nome"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: O erro são os `;` dentro de objeto, você deveria estar usando vírgulas.

Comment: ok, fiz as alterações e realmente era esse o erro, porem ainda não consigo exibir o resultado...

Comment: Por favor mostre o que o seu arquivo.php faz.

Comment: `<?php

echo json_encode($_POST);

?>`

Comment: `data.nNome` também não deveria ser `data.nome`? Seja como for, vai ficar difícil ver o valor mudar se o que você devolve pelo PHP é o mesmo que você acabou de enviar. A linha do `.text()` vai trocar seis por meia dúzia.

Comment: então quanto ao data.nNome ele esta puxando via indice.. que vem atraves da `info = {"nNome" : nome };` , ele deveria aparecer na div em baixo... é somente um teste para aprender e aplicar em outros arquivos...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem vários pequenos erros no seu código, tente esta versão modificada:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
<label>Entre com seu nome:</label>
<input type="text" name="nome"><br>
<input type="button" name="Enviar" value="Enviar">
</form>

<div class="resultado">
Olá, <span class="nome"></span>
</div>

<script>
function ajax(nome){
    var nome = ;
    var info = {"nNome" : nome};

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: "arquivo.php",
        data: info,
    }).done(function(data) {
        data = $.parseJSON(data);
        $(".resultado span.nome").text(data.nNome);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name=Enviar]").click(function(){
      ajax( $("input[name=nome]").val() );
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: muito obrigado.. tem somente que remover a variavel nome... e funciona normal, muito obrigado! agora irei comprar os codigos para ver quais foram meus erros...

Comment: A sua variável nome só existia dentro daquela função de click (porque tinha sido declarada lá). Além disso, a função `ajax` nunca era chamada!

Comment: certo, seguinte testei esse codigo com um esquema para puxar o endereço, ele esta passando o post correto porem não estame retornando o valor...